# Spring Batch RepositoryItemReader Partitioning with multi-threading

Tags: multithreading, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, partitioning

I am using RepositoryItemReader to read a set of data from my database. I would like to partition data from each page and execute those partitions in individual threads using TaskExecutor. I am clueless as to what needs to be done to achieve this. Any guidance/inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the mentioned link https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/scaling-spring-batch-step-partitioning.html, it will give some idea about Paritioning

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, my question is specifically about partitioning using `RepositoryItemReader` . I am aware about that article in java code geeks and Spring Batch partitioning in general, but have difficulty in implementing this for my ORM style.